# Ошибки в foreach. Не могу извлечь информацию

Tags: php

Пытаюсь получить информацию из таблицы через модуль (хочу создать метод редактирования новости):

```
foreach ($this->newsList as $item){
  $item->item['id'];
}
```

Но выдает ошибку:

> Undefined property: View::$newsList ...
>   Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Код модуля выглядит так:

```
public function newsList()
{
    return $this->db->select('SELECT id, title, message, newslink, imagelink, realms FROM news');
}
```

И контроллер:

```
$this->view->newsList = $this->model->newsList();
$this->view->render('editnews/index');
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($this->newsList() as $item) {
  $item->item['id'];
}
```